# Python, Django, smtp.gmail.com did not work

Tags: python, django, email

I have some problem with django and smtp. There is my code:

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '**********@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**form.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    full_name = forms.CharField(required = False)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField() 

def contact_admin(request):
    # check if form was posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)

        # check whether user data is valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            form_email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            form_message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
            form_full_name = form.cleaned_data.get("full_name")


            # send email
            subject = 'Site contact form'
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = [from_email, 'malfar@ukr.net']
            contact_message = "%s: %s via %s" %(form_full_name, form_message, form_email)
            try:
                send_mail(subject, contact_message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=True)
            except Exception:
                message = 'Error' 
            else:
                message = 'Send!'

    # if there was not POST render blank form
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contact_admin/form_admin.html', {'form': form})
```

**form.html**

```
<form action='{% url "contact_admin" %}' method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Надіслати" name="send_button" />
</form>
```

The problem is - when I'm trying send a mail, the page starts downloading and it's taking a long time, and I must to stop it. There are no errors or something like that. I assume the problem in settings.py but I dont know how to fix it

I use django 1.8.3 
my OS - Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)

sorry for my bad english))

Comment: `fail_silently=True` won't raise an exception, so there's a start. Sending e-mail will usually require some time (milliseconds that is), it could be an option to do it in a subprocess/task

Comment: if a put [fail_silently=False] result will be the same. I understand that ending e-mail will usually require some time, but in my case its minutes not milliseconds

Comment: what do you mean by `when I'm trying send a mail, the page starts downloading` ? Also, do away with the try..except - you will see what the exception type is..

Comment: Sending mail via `smtp.gmail.com` doesn't work anymore. Sign up for Mandrill (or Mailchimp). These services are free up to a limit.

Comment: Thanks - I sign up for Mandrill. It`s work!